# Why can't I upload to google photos with this code from python (google photos api using REST from Python)?

Tags: python, rest, google-photos-api

I'm following the guide at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwAwG-SEaRM to upload an image to Google Photos with Python, but I'm getting this error: I could almost swear it worked the first time, but I cannot be sure:

"**Exception has occurred:** ConnectionError
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='photoslibrary', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /googleapis.com/v1/uploads (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001529E1CB790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
File ".....**MAIN.py**", line 49, in 
response = requests.post(upload_url, data=img, headers = headers)"

**The Code in python I'm executing is from MAIN.py:**

```
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import requests
from googlescript import Create_Service

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

API_NAME = 'photoslibrary'
API_VERSION = 'v1'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = dir_path + "\\" + "fotomonimaton.json"
print(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE)
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing']
 
service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

# LIST ALBUMS, WORKS OK
#######################
#print(service.albums().list().execute())


# UPLOAD IMAGE - FAILS
#######################

image_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'images')

upload_url='https://photoslibrary/googleapis.com/v1/uploads'
token = pickle.load(open('token_photoslibrary_v1.pickle','rb'))

headers= {
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+ token.token,
    'Content-type':'application/octet-stream',
    'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol':'raw',
    'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': "totoro name.jpg"
    
}
 
filename = 'totoro.jpg'

image_file = os.path.join(image_dir,filename)

img = open(image_file,'rb').read()

##############
# FAILS HERE #
##############
response = requests.post(upload_url, data=img, headers = headers)

# it does not even reach this line, as it fails before
# Upload the image

request_body ={
    'newMediaItems':
    [
        {
            'description': filename,
            'simpleMediaItem': 
            {
                'uploadToken': response.content.decode('utf-8')
            }
        }
    ] 
}

upload_response = service.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=request_body).execute()
```

**... and the googlescript.py that contains CreateService(...) is this:**

```
import pickle
import os
import datetime
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
 
    cred = None
 
    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
     
    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)
 
    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()
 
        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)
 
    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return None
 
def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

The code initializes the service successfuly, gets the authentication token and the image without problems, but fails in the calling "response = requests.post(upload_url, data=img, headers = headers)" with that exception.

I'm reviewing carefully the code but I cannot find where is the problem...

LOTS of thanks in advance,

Roger

Answer (score 0):

Ops! It was such a petty-typo:

https://photoslibrary/googleapis.com/v1/uploads

should be

https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads

Now I can confirm it works...